# How to check source of action in javafx using scene builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

For example, suppose there are two buttons for two persons to submit their id photograph and it has the functionality of file chooser and we want to get the file path with respect to the person. Means in the database person 1 column should hold the value of person1's id's file path. So how should i check which button is being clicked in order to store it in correct column. Hope you understood my problem..

Comment: Typically you register a different handler with each button. Then it is clear which button was pressed.

Comment: Yes, but i am using scene builder so how to register a handler with that???

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Choose a different controller method for the `onAction` property of each button.

Comment: Alternatively you can get the source from the `ActionEvent` parameter passed to the handler method. Using different handler methods would be preferable though...

Answer (score 0):

on scene builder you can precise the onAction method so you can choose diffrent methods from the controller each do a diffrent action

Comment: you already know the source cause you ll implement for each button different function button1 function1 button2 function2 so in function1 you ll know that is button1 and function2 the source is button2

Comment: But i am using the same function ie. for File chooser for all the buttons.

Comment: you can use ActionEvent then  event.getSource() but i don't recomend that because every time you ll have to heck conditions better to use different function